# How I can calculate the hand position on a clock background?

Tags: technique-selection

I have an old quartz clock mechanism and I want to use it in a custom clock body.

I can easily calculate and place the 12, 3, 6, and 9 positions, but how I can calculate the other positions?

Comment: Do you need just the 12 hour positions or also need to mark the 60 minute positions?

Comment: 12-hout positions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a compass, the drawing kind, not the magnetic kind, you can create the intermediate locations for the hours.

https://youtu.be/2Vshz0kqZh4

The video above shows the process, but I was skeptical until I realized that it's a collection of overlapping equilateral triangles. Equilateral triangles have 60° in each vertex. You want to segment the 90° of the currently created locations (12, 3, 6, 9) into three pieces, 30° each. 90° - 60° = 30°

If you create an equilateral triangle with the base on the 3:00 line, for example, the 60° line of the triangle becomes the 1:00 position. If the triangle is created with the base on the 12:00 line, the triangle provides the 2:00 position.

Comment: You beat me to it.  That was essentially the solution I was writing up (but your answer is a lot more succinct).  :-)  You can reduce the work by marking both sides of the circle while the compass is there (e.g., at 12:00, mark 2:00 and 10:00).

Comment: But on a typical clock are minuted evenly distributed? I mean on every 60 degrees movement on the minutes clock hand 5 minutes are elapsed. If yes I can make some sort of a script that creates an overlapping image for a clock.

Comment: Every 30° movement of the minute hand is five minutes: 12 times 5 = 60 (minutes), 30° x 12 = 360° (full circle). As this is the crafting SE, I suspected you were attempting to construct a physical clock, hence the answer. For programming, seek professional help (grin).

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas, the hour hand moves from one hour mark to the next in 60 minutes, so the minutes affect the position of the hour hand, but not the hour marker.